# Calling method on const object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a piece of code written like this:

```
  private get headers(): Headers {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.auth.tokenSnapshot}`);
    return headers;
  }
```

`headers` is declared `const`.  (This is Angular 4 code, so `Headers` comes from [here](https://angular.io/api/http/Headers)).

In TypeScript, is it OK to call a mutating method on an instance variable declared `const`?

In C++, this would not be possible unless the `Set` method were itself declared `const`, but I don't know if the same can be said of TypeScript.

Comment: Just read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), which says *The `const` declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Const doesn't mean your object is immutable, just that it cannot be reassigned.

This is ok:

```
const headers = {};
headers.myProp = 'test';
```

This isn't:

```
const headers = {};
headers = 'test';
```

Answer (score 0):

The `const` declaration only prevents a variable from being reassigned. It still allows for objects and their properties to be mutated. So yes, you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

That is OK. In typescript `const varName = new Object();` means that you cannot reassign new value to that variable (`varName = otherVarName`), but object itself can mutate